# How do I trigger jQuery .click() after replacing content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML looks like this

```
<div id="current">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="data1">
  <div class="foo"><p>Some Text</p></div>
</div>

<span onclick="replace()">Click to replace div</span>
```

My JQuery/javascript is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foo').click(function() {
    alert('worked');
  })
})

function replace() {
   $('#current').html($('.data1').html());
}
```

The alert triggers fine on the .foo class within the .data1 div but after replacing the contents of #current with .data1, the onclick event doesn't trigger on the .foo class within the first div.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.html()` will create new HTML element but the event will not follow. You need to append a DOM element. The DOM element should be a clone of the original:

```
$('#current').empty().append($('.data1').clone(true));
```

- [`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [`.empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)
- [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: This is exactly the same as `$('#current').html($('.data1').html());`

Comment: @AndreasFurster the difference to note is that one inserts a *HTML String* and the other one a *DOM element* with the handlers.

Comment: @AndreasFurster no its not, `.html()` take the text content. This mean that the event will not follow. `append` will use the DOM element itself with all the data that come with it. Using clone will duplicate the element instead of moving it and passing `true` as parameter mean it's passing the Event data of the element and all its childrens.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dynamically appending the element, use [event-delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$('div').on('click', '.foo', function() {
  alert('worked');
})
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. Event delegation is more "obvious" in what is happening and no additional coding required.

Comment: @LeeTaylor yup :) Thanks BTW